# Interpretation of riddle

Tags: translation, wordplay

This riddle is said to have been written by either Paul Lindau about Oskar Blumenthal or vice versa, and sent back from the recipient to the sender as it could apply equally to either.

> Die erste Hälfte ist duftig, die zweite luftig und das Ganze ist schuftig.

I can see how this can give Blumenthal - with duftig giving Blumen and luftig indicating Tal. I'm stuck on how this can alternatively give Lindau though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Eine Linde* is a lime tree / linden tree. Its blossoms are quite "duftig".

*Eine Au* is a meadow or a wetland. I don't know about "luftig", but it's surely not less luftig than a "Tal", and we have to take into consideration that the adjective also had to rhyme.